# Add condition to for statement if not first run

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following for statement:

```
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=s, cursor=current_cursor).items():
```

However I dont need `, cursor=current_cursor` to be ran on the first run through.

The only way I can think of doing this is two separate for statements with an if statement.

Is there a less sloppy way to do this?

Comment: Likely, no. If there are many such arguments, using `**kwargs` in function call can be easier. But obviously not in your case.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the first run'?

Answer (score 2):

```
tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=s, cursor=None if first_time else current_cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if first_time:
    first_time = False
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_names)
else:
    cursor = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=s, cursor=current_cursor)

for item in cursor.items():
    whatever(item)
```

Initialize `first_time` to `True` somewhere appropriate.

Comment: It might be sufficient to use `current_cursor is None` to indicate the first time, at which point the `Cursor` constructor can be moved outside the if